How to show total based on categories?
Let's say I have sample table data in excel file like in this link.
It shows total amount on top column by this formula =SUM(List[Cost]).
Can we create one more table right side showing total based on category and sub total based on type in it?
Tried different formulas like SUMIFS (=SUMIFS(ExpenseTable[Amount], ExpenseTable[Category], "electric")) but not working.
Please suggest.

I am not sure why the post is disliked even I posted as per community guidelines and the steps I tried.

I assume, that this is not a relevant platform for excel, due programming question are offtopic. Suggestions and opinions are also offtopic, this site is fact based. I would suggest that you take a look at chatgpt if a formula is not working in the current point of view

Yes you can create another table beside the one you are working with.

Formula in
H5: =UNIQUE(List[category])

I5: =SUMPRODUCT((List[category]=H5)*(List[Cost]))

K5: =UNIQUE(List[Type])

L5: =SUMPRODUCT((List[Type]=K5)*(List[Cost]))


Adjust references as needed.
You may convert newly created data set into Table.

